Importing Specific Data from a Text File
I am quite new to Mathematica. I have a text file that upon importing has a repetitive structure with characters included. I need to extract only the following in numbers only (no letters, dash lines, or commas) and store them in consecutive five columns (date, time, measurement value 1, measurement value 2, measurement value 3).
My imported data file looks like this:
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:47
Measurement: 22.10,924.89,43.43
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:51
Measurement: 22.09,924.89,43.42
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:54
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.44
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:57
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.48
------------------------- 

I've tried splitting but I just keep getting a null output {}
Any help is really appreciated.

Given text file

Then one way could be
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
data = Import["input.txt", "Table"]);
p = Pick[Flatten@data, 
   Map[Not, 
    StringContainsQ[
     Flatten@data, {"---", "Date", "and", "Time", "Measurement"}]]];
p = Partition[p, {3}]; (*3 because fields values: date, time, measurement*)
c = Map[StringSplit[#, ","] &, p[[All, 3]]];
Map[Flatten, Transpose[{p[[All, 1 ;; 2]], c}]];
Grid[%, Frame -> All]



Thank you All. Thank you Nasser, it worked.

Assuming the provided text is in a file:
data = ReadList["C:/data.txt", "String"]; 

list = data //
        StringSplit //
       Flatten //
      Map[
       StringDelete[
        LetterCharacter .. | Repeated["-", {2, ∞}]]] //
     Replace[#, "" | ":" :> Nothing, 1] & //
    Sequence @@@ StringSplit[#, ","] & //
   SemanticInterpretation //
  SequenceCases[#,
    k : {a_?DateObjectQ
       , Except[_?DateObjectQ]
       , b__?NumericQ} :> k
    ] &




The number of measurements can vary as long as these are detectable with NumericQ.

text =    
    "Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:47
    Measurement: 22.10,924.89,43.43
    -------------------------
    Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:51
    Measurement: 22.09,924.89,43.42
    -------------------------
    Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:54
    Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.44
    -------------------------
    Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:57
    Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.48
    -------------------------"


Query[All, {4, 5, 7, 8, 9}] @
 Partition[StringSplit[text, {","," ","\n"}], 10]


{{"2024-04-01", "08:42:47", "22.10", "924.89", "43.43"},
{"2024-04-01", "08:42:51", "22.09", "924.89", "43.42"},
{"2024-04-01", "08:42:54", "22.09", "924.90", "43.44"},
{"2024-04-01", "08:42:57", "22.09", "924.90", "43.48"}}


text = "Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:47
Measurement: 22.10,924.89,43.43
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:51
Measurement: 22.09,924.89,43.42
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:54
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.44
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:57
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.48
------------------------- ";

With[{
    trim = RegularExpression@"[\n-]*$",
    delimiter = {"Date and Time: ", "Measurement: ", " ", ","}
},
    Partition[
        StringReplace[#, trim -> ""] & /@ StringSplit[text, delimiter],
    5]
]


Given a string like this:
text = "Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:47
Measurement: 22.10,924.89,43.43
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:51
Measurement: 22.09,924.89,43.42
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:54
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.44
-------------------------
Date and Time: 2024-04-01 08:42:57
Measurement: 22.09,924.90,43.48
-------------------------"

Here's how you can split the string into a 2D array:
StringSplit[
  StringSplit[
    text, {RegularExpression["\n-+\n"], RegularExpression["\n-+"]}],
    {"\nMeasurement: ", "Date and Time: ", " ", ","}]

This assumes that the formatting is consistent for all your possible inputs.
The entries are all strings. Do you need to convert to actual numbers, dates, and times?
I don't know what you mean by "store them in consecutive five columns". Do you need to export this in some specific format?

Thank you lericr. I exported the processed document.
